# MongoDB: Upsert with array filter

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have collection like this:

```py
mc.db.collection.insert_many([
    {"key_array": [1], "another_array": ["a"]},
    {"key_array": [2, 3], "another_array": ["b"]},
    {"key_array": [4], "another_array": ["c", "d"]},    
])
```

And I'm using this kind of updates:

```py
mc.db.collection.update_one(
    {"key_array": 5},
    {"$addToSet": {"another_array": "f"}},
    upsert=True
)
```

It works good with updates, but I have trouble when trying to upsert:
It creates a document with a non-array `key_array` field, like this

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId(...)
    "key_array": 5,
    "another_array": ["f"]
}
```

while I want to have this one

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId(...)
    "key_array": [5],
    "another_array": ["f"]
}
```

Also, I cannot use the `{"key_array": [5]}` style query, because it won't match the existing array with length > 1.

So, is there any chance to save such behavior on updates, and receive the correct document structure on inserts?

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should help.
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/setOnInsert/

```
mc.db.collection.update_one(
    {"key_array": 5},
    {
        "$addToSet": {"another_array": "f"},
        "$setOnInsert": {"key_array": [5], ...}
    },
    upsert=True
)
```

Answer (score 0):

how about this one.

```
db.collection.update({
  "key_array": 5
},
{
  "$addToSet": {
    "another_array": "f",
    
  },
  "$set": {
    "key_array": [
      5
    ]
  }
},
{
  "upsert": true
})
```

https://mongoplayground.net/p/4YdhKuzr2I6

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your response Your option will perform nicely on insert, but when update it can overwrite the existing array. E.g. if we already have a document like this {"key_array": [5, 6], "another_array": ["x"]}

Answer (score 0):

Ok, finally I had solved this issue with two consecutive updates, the first as specified in the question - upserts with non-array query field, and the second which converts the field to an array if it belongs to another type.

```py
from pymongo import UpdateOne

bulk = [
    UpdateOne(
        {"key_array": 6},
        {"$addToSet": {"another_array": "e"}},
        upsert=True
    ),
    UpdateOne(
        {
            "$and": [{"key_array": 6},
                     {"key_array": {"$not": {"$type": "array"}}}]
        },
        [{"$set": { "key_array": ["$key_array"]}}]
    )
]

mc.db.collection.bulk_write(bulk)
```

But I'm still looking for a more elegant way to do such a thing.